# CDE, SQL data sources and String parameter

Tags: sql, parameter-passing, datasource, pentaho

I met with some problem with using a string parameter in the SQL over a [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) datasource. In fact, I need to build this query:

```
select name, some_field1, some_field2
from my_table
where name in (${param_name_filter})
```

But it doesn't work.
I tried to change my query (just for testing) and removed a parameter from the query:

```
select name, some_field1, some_field2
from my_table
where name in ('name 1', 'name 2')
```

But it doesn't work either. As a result, I get the message "no data found".
Where did I make a mistake?

The Pentaho log file is below, but all these messages I get when Pentaho starts (not when dashboar is working).

```
2013-11-07 13:53:39,651 WARN  [org.pentaho.hadoop.shim.HadoopConfigurationLocator] Unable to load Hadoop Configuration from "file:///usr/share/pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/kettle/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/mapr". For more information enable debug logging.
2013-11-07 13:53:42,827 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageManager] Unresolved dependency for package: org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.extensions.datasources.cda.CdaModule
2013-11-07 13:53:42,848 WARN  [org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.base.boot.PackageSorter] A dependent module was not found in the list of known modules.
2013-11-07 13:53:46,071 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.PooledDatasourceSystemListener: PooledDatasourceSystemListener.ERROR_0003 - Unable to pool datasource object: MySqlConnection caused by java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2013-11-07 13:53:46,719 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error: Pentaho
2013-11-07 13:53:46,720 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-class org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager: PluginManager.ERROR_0011 - Failed to register plugin cdc
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PlatformPluginRegistrationException: PluginManager.ERROR_0017 - Could not load lifecycle listener [pt.webdetails.cdc.plugin.CdcLifeCycleListener] for plugin cdc
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.bootStrapPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:163)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.registerPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:197)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.reload(DefaultPluginManager.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.startup(PluginAdapter.java:42)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:342)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/core/MembershipListener
    at pt.webdetails.cdc.plugin.CdcLifeCycleListener.<clinit>(CdcLifeCycleListener.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.bootStrapPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:160)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.core.MembershipListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 39 more
2013-11-07 13:53:46,723 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error end:
2013-11-07 13:53:47,043 WARN  [pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine] Falling back to built-in config
2013-11-07 13:53:51,917 WARN  [pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine] Falling back to built-in config
2013-11-07 13:53:57,529 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error: Pentaho
2013-11-07 13:53:57,529 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-class org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager: PluginManager.ERROR_0011 - Failed to register plugin cdb
com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Cannot connect to any configured remote nodes: 127.0.0.1:2424
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createNetworkConnection(OStorageRemote.java:1686)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createConnectionPool(OStorageRemote.java:1953)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1517)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:176)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.open(OStorageRemoteThread.java:69)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:96)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:114)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.java:43)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentPool.createResource(ODatabaseDocumentPool.java:39)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentPool.createResource(ODatabaseDocumentPool.java:20)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase$1.createNewResource(ODatabasePoolBase.java:67)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase$1.createNewResource(ODatabasePoolBase.java:56)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OResourcePool.getResource(OResourcePool.java:66)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.acquire(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:65)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.acquire(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:53)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase.acquire(ODatabasePoolBase.java:114)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine.getConnection(PersistenceEngine.java:137)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine.initializeClass(PersistenceEngine.java:418)
    at pt.webdetails.cdb.CdbLifeCycleListener.init(CdbLifeCycleListener.java:45)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PlatformPlugin.init(PlatformPlugin.java:189)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.registerPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:199)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.reload(DefaultPluginManager.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.startup(PluginAdapter.java:42)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:342)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2013-11-07 13:53:57,533 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error end:
2013-11-07 13:53:58,321 WARN  [pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine] Falling back to built-in config
2013-11-07 13:53:58,340 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 856fca78-4792-11e3-a347-f71d7a81a07e:SOLUTION-ENGINE:scheduler.xaction: Action Sequence execution failed, see details below
| Error Time: 7 ?????? 2013 ?. 13:53:58 MSK
| Session ID: scheduler.xaction
| Instance Id: 856fca78-4792-11e3-a347-f71d7a81a07e
| Action Sequence: scheduler.xaction
| Execution Stack:
EXECUTING ACTION: Scheduler (org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.PojoComponent)
| Action Class: org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.PojoComponent
| Action Desc: Scheduler
| Loop Index (1-based): 0
Stack Trace:org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.ActionExecutionException: RuntimeContext.ERROR_0017 - Action failed to execute
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeComponent(RuntimeContext.java:1325)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeAction(RuntimeContext.java:1262)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.performActions(RuntimeContext.java:1161)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeLoop(RuntimeContext.java:1105)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:987)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.runtime.RuntimeContext.executeSequence(RuntimeContext.java:897)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.executeInternal(SolutionEngine.java:399)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:317)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine.execute(SolutionEngine.java:193)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.BaseRequestHandler.handleActionRequest(BaseRequestHandler.java:159)
    at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzExecute.execute(QuartzExecute.java:198)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)

2013-11-07 13:54:04,286 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error: Pentaho
2013-11-07 13:54:04,286 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-class org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager: PluginManager.ERROR_0011 - Failed to register plugin cdv
com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Cannot connect to any configured remote nodes: 127.0.0.1:2424
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createNetworkConnection(OStorageRemote.java:1686)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.createConnectionPool(OStorageRemote.java:1953)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.openRemoteDatabase(OStorageRemote.java:1517)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote.open(OStorageRemote.java:176)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemoteThread.open(OStorageRemoteThread.java:69)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:96)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:114)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:47)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTxPooled.java:43)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentPool.createResource(ODatabaseDocumentPool.java:39)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentPool.createResource(ODatabaseDocumentPool.java:20)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase$1.createNewResource(ODatabasePoolBase.java:67)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase$1.createNewResource(ODatabasePoolBase.java:56)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OResourcePool.getResource(OResourcePool.java:66)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.acquire(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:65)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolAbstract.acquire(ODatabasePoolAbstract.java:53)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabasePoolBase.acquire(ODatabasePoolBase.java:114)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine.getConnection(PersistenceEngine.java:137)
    at pt.webdetails.cpf.persistence.PersistenceEngine.initializeClass(PersistenceEngine.java:418)
    at pt.webdetails.cdv.CdvLifecycleListener.reInit(CdvLifecycleListener.java:60)
    at pt.webdetails.cdv.CdvLifecycleListener.init(CdvLifecycleListener.java:52)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PlatformPlugin.init(PlatformPlugin.java:189)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.registerPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:199)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.reload(DefaultPluginManager.java:128)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.startup(PluginAdapter.java:42)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:342)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:324)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:291)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:208)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
2013-11-07 13:54:04,291 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error end:
2013-11-07 13:54:05,117 WARN  [org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator] We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [public java.lang.String serializeModels(org.pentaho.metadata.model.Domain,java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.Exception]
2013-11-07 13:56:07,855 WARN  [pt.webdetails.cpf.repository.PentahoRepositoryAccess] hasAccess: .wcdf extension not in acl-files.
2013-11-07 13:56:17,671 ERROR [net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStore] Corrupt index file. Creating new index.
```

Comment: is your datasource being created just fine ??

Comment: what do the server logs say?

Comment: there is nothing in the log file, about working dashboard and get data from MySql server. for any case add log file in my main post.

Comment: i have found how i can solve this problem ([link](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?152268-CDE-SQL-data-sources-and-String-parameter)) but it is'nt good.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) to look at the CDA data calls, and see what param_name_filter is set to. Then fix the issue; hint: make sure it's a string array in the data source definition of the parameter.